# PS/2 keyboard only works up to GRUB, not after OS fully booted

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, kernel-modules, hardware

I have an IBM model F keyboard connected to to my PS/2 port and the keyboard seems to be recognized at first: the lights on the board blink and up to the GRUB menu key presses are being registered. But once I'm past GRUB the keyboard is no longer recognized. I'm running Arch.

I've tried the solution described [here](https://www.archlinux.org/news/linux-313-warning-ps2-keyboard-support-is-now-modular) and added the atkbd module to the `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` but without success.

**Edit**
Output of `dmesg` is in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Gd344qT0) now. The relevant `i8042` parts say: "PNP: No PS/2 controller found".

Comment: Please look at the relevant part of `dmesg` (don't grep) directly after boot (use `ssh` from a second computer to see it, or borrow an USB keyboard somewhere). Especially messages containing `i8042`. If you can't make sense of it, put the whole thing into a pastebin and edit queston with link.

Comment: Linux does seem to have trouble with your ACPI BIOS, judging from the error messages. Also, a PNP03xx legacy device which would indicate a keyboard is not detected, that's why i8042 says "no controller found". This may not be so easy to fix unless you can find out where your PS/2 controller actually sits in I/O space. You can try to play around with the `acpi_osi` boot parameter (google) and pretend you are some version of Windows on boot, sometimes this helps for buggy BIOSes.

Comment: I tried out the `acpi_osi` Windows option but again without success. However when I boot with a "modern" PS/2 keyboard connected and then plug in the model F after the system has fully booted, everything works just fine.

Comment: That's interesting. What's the relevant part of `dmesg` in that case? Possibly the missing PNP03xx and i8042 not working are unrelated, maybe the model F blocks controller detection somehow. The important file seems to be `drivers/input/serio/i8042.c`. I'd modify either `i8042_controller_check` or `i8042_init` to disable initial error checking, recompile it, and see if it recognizes the model F even when plugged in at boot.

Comment: You can also turn on debugging with the `debug` module option, and get more info in `dmesg` or `syslog` that way.